# Functions of functions in calculus

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I have just finished working through a chapter on calculus and have coped OK, answering most of the questions correctly. The chapter dealt with composite functions, along with other topics.

But I just cannot understand this question. I can see we are dealing with functions of functions but they are not set out in a form I can understand. Any help would be appreciated.

In each of the following cases, express $f'$, the derivative of $f$ (with respect to $x$) in terms of $g'$. The number $a$ is constant:

$\begin{align} i) \quad & f(x) = g(x + g(a)) \\
ii) \quad & f(x) = g(a + g(x)) \\
iii) \quad & f(x) = g(x^2) 
\end{align}$

Comment: Can you apply the chain rule to these 3 cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think it will help to point out that these are **not** functions of functions. A composition of functions isn't a function of functions,$^*$ it's just an ordinary function which you might think about as being "built in two (or more) steps."

---

OK, now on to the problem itself. Consider a simpler example. Suppose $$f(x)=g(2x).$$Both $f$ and $g$ are ordinary functions; maybe $f(x)=4x^2$ and $g(x)=2x$. We don't know enough about $f$ to compute $f'(x)$, but we do know enough about **how $f$ relates to $g$** to compute a relationship between $f'$ and $g'$, via the chain rule:

- First, we explicitly write $f$ as a composition of two functions: the outer one is just $g$ itself, and the inner one is $h:x\mapsto 2x$. So $f=g\circ h$.
- That's much more confusing to write than just "$f(x)=g(2x)$," but it makes things clearer for applying the chain rule to get $$f'(x)=g'(h(x))\cdot h'(x)=g'(2x)\cdot 2=2g'(2x).$$ So we've shown $f'(x)=2g'(2x)$; again, this doesn't amount to a computation of $f'$ itself, but it does tell us how to compute $f'$ *in terms of* $g'$.

Now your cases are a bit more complicated, but they're using the same principle. That first bulletpoint is going to be crucial, so focusing on the first problem for simplicity:

> Suppose $f(x)=g(x+g(a))$. What's a function $h$ such that $$f=g\circ h$$ (if you can find this $h$ you'll then be able to just apply the chain rule directly)?

---

$^*$That said, there *is* a genuine "function-of-functions" floating around here - namely, **composition itself**! Composition (of functions $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, for simplicity) is the operation which takes a pair of functions $h_1,h_2$ and spits out the function $h_1\circ h_2$. So composition is a binary function-of-functions.

Comment: So is the derivative: It takes a function and spits out another function.

Answer (score 1):

It is the use of the chain rule. For example

$ii) \quad f(x)=g(x+g(x))$

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{d\big(g(x+g(x))\big)}{d\big(x+g(x)\big)} \frac{d\big(x+g(x)\big)}{dx} = g’(x + g(a))(1 + g’(x))$$

(*the big parenthesis are only there to avoid confusion*)